# When encountered the next record, read all the lines from the prior record using powershell script

Tags: powershell, shell, for-loop, if-statement

I've edited the post with more details description.
My Input.DAT has 3 records, each record starts with "01".

```
   01 firstN1 lastN1
   02 studentid1 sdf   course1
   03 class1 dfg location1
   05 dfgdf
   01 firstN2 lastN2 
   02 studentid2 ert   568  
   03 class2 dfg location2
   01 firstN3 lastN3 
   03 class3 dfg location3
```

My Powershellscript.ps1 file:

```
    foreach-object {  
       $line = $_.tostring()  
      $i= $line.substring(0, 2).trim()    
    
        if($i -eq "01"){  
    $firstname=$line.substring(3,7).trim()  
    $lastname=$line.substring(11,6).trim()}  
   
      
        if($i -eq "02"){  
    $studentid=$line.substring(3,10).trim()
    $course=$line.substring(20,7).trim() }  
      
    
        if($i -eq "03"){  
    $class=$line.substring(3,6).trim()
    $location=$line.substring(14,9).trim()}    
 
if($i -eq "05"){
    ****************}

# need help in below logic   

     Foreach ($x in $1) {   
         if ($x -eq '01') {   
 
    add-content -path outputfile.txt -value   firstname,"|",$lastname,"|",$studentid,"|",$class,"|",$course,"|",$location
 
Clear-Variable -Scope Script firstname*, lastname*, studentid*, class*, course* ,location*
```

My issue is : Current code is looking for the 1st "01" and reading only data(01 firstN1 lastN1 234)to the output file. however i want the logic to be written to check when the loop hits 2nd "01" or/and the $firstname again ,that when we know we have completed reading first set of records , then only read all the previous record to the output file in single line.

```
My Output file(outputfile.txt) looks like this.
       firstname|lastname|studentid|class|course|location
       firstN1|lastN1||||
       firstN2|lastN2|studentid1|class1|course1|location1
       firstN3|lastN3|studentid2|class2|568|location2

Instead of 
       firstname|lastname|studentid|class|course|location
       firstN1|lastN1|studentid1|class1|course1|location1  
       firstN2|lastN2|studentid2|class2|568|location2
       firstN3|lastN3|studentid3|class3|course3|location3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your output doesn't seem possible since your data doesn't contain a studentid3 or class3.

That aside, I recommend a different approach to extracting and outputting the data.

For the sake of this example I am creating a 3 record text file.

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
01 firstN1 lastN1 234  
02 studentid1 sdf 345  
03 class1 dfg 456  
01 firstN2 lastN2 567  
02 studentid2 ert 568  
03 class2 dfg 890
01 firstN3 lastN3 012 
02 studentid3 ert 876 
03 class3 dfg 321
'@ | Set-Content $tempfile -Encoding UTF8
```

If you know there will always be two lines after then you can use the `-Context` parameter of `Select-String` to group each 3 line section.

```
Select-String -Path $tempfile -Pattern '01' -Context 0,2
```

We simply match 01 and select the matching line and 2 lines following. `context 0,2`

Now if we send each grouping of lines through a `Foreach-Object` loop we can manipulate/parse the text. There are several approaches, many prefer `Switch` with the `-Regex` parameter. We craft our regex patterns to grab the desired text. We will use two different switch statements as you'll see, one for the matching `$_.line` and the other for the `$_.Context.PostContext` lines. After the switch statements we should have all four variables populated so we'll make a `PSCustomObject` and then simply pipe the entire output to `Export-Csv` specifying your desired delimiter.

```
Select-String -Path $tempfile -Pattern '01' -Context 0,2 | ForEach-Object {
    Switch -Regex ($_.Line){
        '01\s{1,}(.+?)\s{1,}(.+?)\s'{$firstname,$lastname = $matches.1,$matches.2}
    }
    Switch -Regex ($_.Context.PostContext){
        '02\s{1,}(.+?)\s'{$studentid = $matches.1}
        '03\s{1,}(.+?)\s'{$classid = $matches.1}
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FirstName = $firstname
        LastName  = $lastname
        StudentID = $studentid
        ClassID   = $classid
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path outputfile.csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

The Csv format will look just like your desired text file with the added benefit of column headers and being ready to reimport and use for other tasks.

```
Get-Content .\outputfile.csv

"FirstName"|"LastName"|"StudentID"|"ClassID"
"firstN1"|"lastN1"|"studentid1"|"class1"
"firstN2"|"lastN2"|"studentid2"|"class2"
"firstN3"|"lastN3"|"studentid3"|"class3"
```

I'm simply showing the contents with `Get-Content`. To use the data you should use `Import-Csv` and work with objects. Objects are just one of the things that make powershell so powerful.

**Regex details**

`01`,`02`,`03` - literal match

`\s{1,}`       - one or more spaces

`()`           - capture group

`.+?`          - match one or more characters, non greedy

`\s`           - exactly one space

**Edit**

You're likely to end up with invalid data if it's really sporadically populated like your updated sample. There will be a location of 456 in the first set and the third set has no student ID. A more realistic example will surely help us help you. I would not output this to CSV as the columns won't line up. You could enforce a blank student ID if required but it seems more likely it was left out in error.

```
$text = @'
   01 firstN1 lastN1 234      dfgh
   02 studentid1 sdf course1 345  
   03 class1 dfg 456                35        dfg
   05 dfgdf dghfg    sdfh                123       45
   01 firstN2 lastN2 567  
   02 studentid2 ert 568  
   03 class2 dfg location2 890
   01 firstN3 lastN3 567  
   03 class3 dfg location3 890
'@

$text -split '(?=01)' | ForEach-Object {
    $ht = [ordered]@{}

    Switch -Regex ($_){
        '01\s{1,}(.+?)\s{1,}(.+?)\s'{$ht.FirstName,$ht.LastName = $matches.1,$matches.2}
        '02\s{1,}(.+?)\s'{$ht.StudentID = $matches.1}
        '03\s{1,}(.+?)\s{1,}\w{3,}\s{1,}(.+?)\s'{$ht.ClassID,$ht.LocationID = $matches.1,$matches.2}
    }

    if($ht.values -ne ''){
        [PSCustomObject]$ht
    }
}
```

output

```
FirstName  : firstN1
LastName   : lastN1
StudentID  : studentid1
ClassID    : class1
LocationID : 456

FirstName  : firstN2
LastName   : lastN2
StudentID  : studentid2
ClassID    : class2
LocationID : location2

FirstName  : firstN3
LastName   : lastN3
ClassID    : class3
LocationID : location3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @DougMaurer. My input file doesn't have a fixed set of lines after '01'. What do i do in that case? Also i have a big file with fixed length substring fields in each line like "$lastname=$line.substring(11,6).trim() and so on for more than 100 substrings. I'm new to powershell script. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: I would add those details to your post.

Comment: Going to be next to impossible if there is no consistency. Some have location and others have gibberish?

Comment: If there is no location, we can leave that field as blank in the output. That problem with my code is only populating firstname and lastname correctly, rest of the subfields are off. Since i have `if ($x -eq '01')` it's getting the `01` subfields and adding to the file i think. My logic should be like if the next line is a "01" and firstname is populated,you reached the next record in source file, write all current variables from prior record to an output file.

Comment: I think i wasn't clear. `03 class2 dfg location2 890` if we pull location2 out of the line starting with 03, then the location for `03 class1 dfg 456 ` will be 456. You should probably give more realistic examples of the actual text on the line. Will it really be class then 3 letters then location then 3 numbers?

Comment: it's a fixed length delimited file.  so location size is 9 as per `$location=$line.substring(14,9).trim()`. So, 456 can be location substring. Each record has different values, some substrings could be null also.

Comment: Well hopefully you can combine your code with my suggestion and achieve your desired results. Or someone else may come with another answer.

Comment: I've edited more now. DO you know how to get this code `'01\s{1,}(.+?)\s{1,}(.+?)\s'{$ht.FirstName,$ht.LastName = $matches.1,$matches.2}` from my code `if($i -eq "01"){  
    $firstname=$line.substring(3,7).trim()  
    $lastname=$line.substring(11,6).trim()}  ` since this is fixed length substring? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Line 1 doesn't seem to be the problematic one does it? Seems it's more about line 03. But to answer your question try this `$ht.FirstName,$ht.LastName = $_.substring(3,7).trim() ,$_.substring(3,7).trim()`